# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unable to transform version 2.4 web application namespace to version 2.5

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

we are trying to deploy a application to weblogic12c(12.1.3). While starting the deployment we are getting below error, not sure why?

```
####<Sep 5, 2014 7:51:21 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <localhost> <abc_Server> <[STANDBY]                         ExecuteThread:    '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1409926881629> <BEA-101064> <[WebAppModule(abc:app)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication "C:\XXXXXXXX\abc\webapps\abc\app"
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unable to transform version 2.4 web application namespace to version 2.5.
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppReader2.transformOldSchema(WebAppReader2.java:300)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger._next(VersionMunger.java:348)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.next(VersionMunger.java:230)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.consumeInputStream(VersionMunger.java:595)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.init(VersionMunger.java:485)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:86)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:62)
at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:50)
```

**Installation details:**

weblogic12c(12.1.3) with java 1.7

Domain also created with java 1.7

classpath env variable to set to java 1.7

I verified web.xml and its correct i has version="2.5" too, it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
xxx
-->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have a problem with the namespaces. Try replacing the xmlns attribute with this:
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
and xsi:schemaLocation with this:
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"

Actually, weblogic looks inside the namespace to know if it's 2.5 or 2.4. If it finds "j2ee", it's 2.4 otherwise it's looking at the version attribute of the web-app tag (see $WL_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-classes.jar, weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppReader2, l262 & 300).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As per javaee 5 specification namespace should be "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee".